Finding the area of the curved figure bounded by $y=x^{2/3}-1$, $y = 8$, and $y = 0$

How do you find the area of the curved figure defined by the graphs of these relations?
$$y = x^{2/3} - 1$$
$$y = 8$$
$$y = 0$$

Regarding this assignment. I realised where the figure is defined: from $0$ to $27$ (on the $x$-axis). Here you have to integrate by parts sort of. But I'm not sure. Someone told me that the definite integral should be taken (from $1$ to $27$), but this is nonsense as it is defined from $0$ to $27$? Or am I wrong?
Can you please tell me which definite integral I should find?
I understand I have to subtract the area where it lies $(8\times27=216)$ from the area of the bottom part (found by the definite integral)?
Can you show me in a general way what to find and subtract from what? Help me please.

try to draw the plane segment bounded by the three curves you are given. this should greatly aid your intuition as to which boundaries to use for your integral. hint: the person who told you to integrate from 1 to 27 was correct.

You seem to also be bounding this region by the line $x=0$?

Just integrate from $x=1$ to $x=27$ to get the area $A$
$$
A= \int_1^{27}x^{2/3} - 1\mathrm{d}x=\frac{596}{5}.
$$
EDIT: OP's original version didnot show cleanly which part for the area. My bad as well!
Above is the area bounded by the curve to $x-$axis from $x=1$ to $x=27$, to get the bounded area $A'$ formed by the curve $x=0$, $y=0$ and $y=8$, one just needs to subtract $A$ from the rectangle $8\times27=216$, i.e.,
$$
A'=8\times27-A=\frac{484}{5}.
$$

My reading of the problem is that the goal is to find the area enclosed by the four curves:
$$ y = x^{2/3}-1, \qquad y= 8, \qquad y=0, \qquad\text{and}\qquad x=0. $$
The original problem does not explicitly bound the region by $x=0$, but it seems implicit from the way in which the problem is stated.  If the region is not being bounded by $x=0$, then the actual region of interest is doubled (the area bounded between the three curves given in terms of $y=\dots$ is symmetric across the $y$-axis).
To my understanding, that is the shaded region in the figure below (which is very much not to scale).

Off the top of my head, I see several reasonable approaches:
Integrate with Respect to $x$
The shaded region can be broken into two pieces:

On the interval $[0,1]$, the shaded region is bounded above by $y=8$, and bounded below by $y=0$.  This is a rectangle with area $8$, which can also be seen as an integral:
\begin{align} \int_{0}^{1} (\text{upper bound}) - (\text{lower bound}) \,\mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{1} 8 - 0 \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 8x \bigr]_{x=0}^{1} \\
&= 8. \end{align}

On the interval $[1,27]$, the shaded region is bounded above by $y=8$, and is bounded below by $y=x^{2/3} - 1$.  Therefore the area in that region is
\begin{align} \int_{1}^{27} (\text{upper bound}) - (\text{lower bound}) \,\mathrm{d}x 
&= \int_{1}^{27} 8 - (x^{2/3} - 1) \,\mathrm{dx} \\
&= 9x - \frac{3}{5} x^{5/3} \bigr]_{x=1}^{27} \\
&= \frac{444}{5}. \end{align}


Adding these two areas gives
$$ \text{Total Area} = 8 + \frac{444}{5} = \frac{484}{5}. $$
Integrate with Respect to $y$
Alternatively, note that if $y = x^{2/3} - 1$, then $x = (y-1)^{3/2}$.  So the region could be described, instead, as that area bounded to the left of
$$ x = (y-1)^{3/2} $$
on the interval $y \in [0,8]$.  This integral is then
\begin{align} \int_{0}^{8} (y+1)^{3/2} \,\mathrm{d}y
&= \int_{1}^{9} t^{3/2} \,\mathrm{d}t && (\text{CoV: $t=y+1$}) \\
&= \left. \frac{2}{5} t^{5}{2} \right]_{t=1}^{9} \\
&= \frac{484}{5}.
\end{align}
Regard the Area as a Rectangle Minus a Piece
Another approach is to observe that the entire area can be seen as a rectangle with sides of length $8$ and $27$, less the area under $y = x^{2/3} -1 $ on the interval $[1,27]$.

The area removed is
$$ \int_{1}^{27} x^{2/3} - 1 \,\mathrm{d}x
= \left. \frac{3}{5} x^{5/3} - x \right]_{x=1}^{27}
= \frac{596}{5}.$$
Then
$$ \text{Total Area} = 8(27) - \frac{596}{5} = \frac{484}{5}. $$
